# Fancybox and SharePoint 2010 - position of the iframe

Tags: sharepoint-2010, fancybox-2

Has anyone experienced problems with using fancybox one a SharePoint page?

I have followed all the instructions and the link opens the iframe with the content but the iframe is opening in one of the divs at the top of the page rather than in the middle of the page.

I have a feeling it is to do with the class of the div as it is called 'Wrapper'.

Does fancybox use 'wrapper' as an explicit value for where the iframe will open?  Is this something that I can change as i can't change the div class (that is all set from central admin).

Comment: difficult to guess what you are doing unless you post your relevant code or provide a link that reproduces the issue. My guess is either the fancybox version of the js file doesn't match with the fancybox css file -or- your page is running in quirks mode. But again, it's just a guess

Answer (score 0):

@JFK - thanks for the pointers - turned out to be an older JS file version.  I changed that to the latest version and it works perfectly.